# A confusing point in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to create my new html and css files easilt throught clicking file then clicking create new file before asking me about the required technology and usually select html or css but now I get confused because the options have been changed as they appear in the attached screenshoot,

now how can I create new html and css files ???

and what the difference between new text file and new file ?

[My VS after the new update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YAfj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, new text file will create a simple .txt file whereas New File will allow you to choose your desired language